# django bulk_Create error with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class UserMap(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_map'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    map = models.ForeignKey(Map)
```

When I try to insert objects using the `UserMap.objects.bulk_create`, I keep getting the following:

`(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('db'.'user_map', CONSTRAINT 'user_id_refs_id_9490e10f418065' FOREIGN KEY ('user_id') REFERENCES 'user
' ('id'))')`

I find this strange because I can insert the exact values into the db manually, but it doesn't work when i do `bulk_create` or `save()`. Is there a reason for this strange error? Has anybody noticed any issues with `bulk_create` and ForeignKeys?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you used to create the `UserMap` objects? It should be something to the effect of:
`UserMap.objects.bulk_create([UserMap(user=id, map=id)])`

Or, if you've solved this issue, please update with the answer. Thanks!

Comment: The code you have is correct. Honestly, been a long time since I looked at this. I can't remember my exact solution. But I think it was something like this:
    `sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="from_user")`
    `receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="to_user")`